# Python: \n added after splitting csv file

Tags: python

Find this really weird, for some reason '\n' is added to the last entry in my list when I split a line from a .csv file.

**Script**

```
    f = open("temp.csv")
    lines = f.readlines()
    headings = lines[0]
    global heading_list
    heading_list = headings.split(";")
    print headings
```

I've printed out just headings itself and it doesn't have '\n' when at the end of it, it seems to be only when it's split at the semi colon.

**.csv file**

```
timestamp;%usr;%nice;%sys;%iowait;%steal;%irq;%soft;%guest;%idle
10-20-39;6.53;0.00;4.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;89.45
10-20-41;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
10-20-43;1.98;0.00;1.98;5.45;0.00;0.50;0.00;0.00;90.10
10-20-45;0.50;0.00;1.51;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;97.99
10-20-47;0.50;0.00;1.50;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;98.00
10-20-49;0.50;0.00;1.01;3.02;0.00;0.00;0.00;0.00;95.48
```

**Output from script**

[image: Script Output]

Comment: If you're using a `CSV` file why don't you try the `CSV Module`?

Comment: Your variable `headings` surely contains a `\n` (or `\r\n`) at the end, that’s why it forms the first **line** of the file :) Depending on the method you use for printing the variable it will be shown explicitly or just go to the next line in the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read a line in Python, the end of line character is not removed. You have to do this manually, for example with `line.rstrip("\r\n")`. It's not a problem with `split`, but with `readlines`.

Comment: More specifically, `headings.strip()` would solve the problem.

Comment: @Vincent Sure, but I prefer rstrip("\r\n"), which only affects end of lines. Probably harmless with CSV, but cleaner anyway.

Comment: I just tried rstrip and strip on headings, both didn't work, the \n is still at the end of ' %idle '. When I run my script, the output is the same as in the picture.

Comment: @MOS182 It does not modify the string in place, so you have to write `headings = headings.rstrip("\r\n")` or directly `heading_list = headings.rstrip("\r\n").split()`

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut just tried headings = headings.rstrip("\r\n") which worked fine :) previously I just did headings.rstrip("\r\n") which didn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - use the [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) module. See below.

The new line character is present in the data that was read from the file. `readlines()` does not remove it, and in fact you will find that the new line character *is* present in `headings` :

```
>>> headings = lines[0]
>>> headings
'timestamp;%usr;%nice;%sys;%iowait;%steal;%irq;%soft;%guest;%idle\n'
```

A better way is to use `splitlines()` on the data read from the file. This *will* remove new lines, regardless of the type (`'\n'`, `'\r\n'`, `'\r'`):

```
>>> with open("temp.csv") as f:
>>>     lines = f.read().splitlines()
>>>     headings = lines[0]
>>> headings
'timestamp;%usr;%nice;%sys;%iowait;%steal;%irq;%soft;%guest;%idle'
```

`readlines()` fails for Mac newlines (`'\r'`), so you should open the file with [universal newline support](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.3.html?highlight=universal#pep-278-universal-newline-support) by specifying `'rU'` as the mode:

```
with open('temp.csv', 'rU') as f:
    ...
```

One other thing worth mentioning is that processing files this way can consume a lot of memory if the file is large because the whole file is read in one go. Instead it is more efficient to iterate over the file like this:

```
with open('temp.csv', 'rU') as f:
    heading_list = next(f).rstrip().split(';')    # headings on the first line
    for line in f:
        process_data_row(line.rstrip().split(';'))
```

Finally, the real answer. You can avoid all of the mess above by using the csv module:

```
import csv

with open('temp.csv', 'rU') as csv_file:    # NB. 'rU' is important for handling mac newlines
    csv_data = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
    heading_list = next(csv_data)
    for row in csv_data:
        process_data_row(row)
```